# Eclipse to MySql via SSH proxy connects but can't query without a database qualifier

Tags: eclipse

I'm using Eclipse Juno with the SQL Explorer plugin. I've set up an SSH tunnel for port 3306 via Putty to my production server and have successfully connected to that server's MySql instance. I can view the database's schema as well as getting a preview of a table's data. When I try to execute a basic SELECT query, without a database qualifier on the table, Eclipse gives me a NullPointerException with no additional information. However, if I include the database qualifier, it works.

The database selector in Eclipse/SQL Explorer is set correctly and everything works as expected if I'm not running over the SSH tunnel (e.g. locally or a direct remote connection).

Is there something that I'm overlooking?

Comment: What SQL Explorer plug-in? Can you find and show the stack trace in your workspace's .metadata\.log file?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, nitind. That led me to figure out the cause and a solution. The error was coming from the plugin when it tries to write to its history file. According to this, http://sourceforge.net/p/eclipsesql/discussion/450662/thread/f1e73461, there's a known bug that occurs when you rename a database connection which is what I had done. Clearing the history file solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by a bug in the SQL Explorer plugin (see http://sourceforge.net/p/eclipsesql/discussion/450662/thread/f1e73461). The symptom was a red herring. The NPE would occur when the plugin tried to write to its history file. Clearing the history file resolved the problem.